# toggle class when body has a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add the class `untransform` when the body has a class of `modal-open`?

html structure is like this

```
 <body>
     <div id="inner-wrap">

      ....
    </div>
  <body>
```

and if when the body has a class of `modal-open` i want to add the class `untransform`  to `div#inner-wrap`.

```
 <body class="modal-open">
     <div id="inner-wrap" class="untransform">

      ....
    </div>
  <body>
```

How do I do this with toggleClass method?

Comment: You should really redo your question. After reading it three times, I still don't know what you want.

Comment: it helps to read up a little on how to form CSS selectors, which are jQuery's main power. Finding "an element when a parent element has a certain class" is a basic CSS selectors thing, where in this case `body.modal-open #inner-wrap` gets you your specific div. And we use the id rather than `div.untransform` because CSS rules are evaluated right-to-left, and thus having that id on the right is the fastest way to home in on the div, and then have the `body.modal-open` selector either preserve or invalidate it.

Comment: You will need to call toggleclass on the event that toggles body 'modal-open'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$( "#inner-wrap" ).toggleClass(function() {
    if ( $("body").is( ".modal-open" ) ) {
        return "untransform";
    } else {
        return "";
    }
});
```

`<div id="inner-wrap">` will be give a class "untransform" if body has "modal-open" class.

detailed documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: how do u add the class to the correct div? `div#inner-wrap`

Comment: the return value will be used as a class to be added to the element (div) with id="inner-wrap".

Answer (score 1):

The `modal-open` is added to the `<body>` when a modal window is opened. So the right place is to hack the modal window events.

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // Your code when body has .modal-open
});
```

Or, you can do something like check the changes of `<body>`, using manual triggering of events and binding that event.

```
$("body").trigger('ClassChanged')
$("body").on('ClassChanged', function(){
    if ($('body').hasClass('modal-open'))
      // Your code when body has .modal-open
});
```